# How to populate data in textbox onchange of two separate dropdownlist in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I'm trying to populate "num" in textbox when "year" and "console" is selected. The database query should run like - select max(num)+1 from table when year = 'someyear' and console = 'someconsole'.
My Controller Action looks like -

```
public function actionGetForNum($yearid , $consoleid)
    {
        $num = Bills::find()->select('(max(num) + 1) as num')->where(['bills_year'=>$yearid])->andWhere(['console'=>$consoleid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($num);
    }
```

I'm using select2 widget to select year and console. Year and console are not dependent on each other.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'bills_year')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Year::find()->orderBy(['yid' => SORT_DESC,])->all(),'year_year','year_year'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Year', 'id' => 'yearid'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'console')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Console::find()->orderBy(['consoleid' => SORT_ASC,])->all(),'console','console'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Console','id' => 'consoleid'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]); ?>
```

And the javascript code I've tried is-

```
<?php
/* start getting the num */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('#yearid').change(function(){   
        getNum();
    });
    $('#consoleid').change(function(){   
        getNum();
    });

    var yearid = $(this).val();
    var consoleid = $(this).val();

    var getNum = $.get('index.php?r=invoice/bills/get-for-num',{ yearid : yearid, consoleid : consoleid }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#bills-num').attr('value',data.num);
        });

});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the num */
?>
```

In this code I'm getting error - `TypeError: getNum is not a function`
Here is the error screen - [image]
Please suggest how to correct it.

**Update** - 
I've changed the javascript code as below -

```
<?php
/* start getting the num */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('#yearid').change(function(){   
        getNum();
    });
    $('#consoleid').change(function(){   
        getNum();
    });

    var yearid = $(this).val();
    var consoleid = $(this).val();

    var getNum = function(){
        var yearid = String($('#yearid').val());
        var consoleid = String($('#consoleid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=invoice/bills/get-for-num',{ yearid : yearid, consoleid : consoleid }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var getNum = data;
        $('#bills-num').val(getNum);
        });

    } ;

});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the num */
?>
```

And I'm getting the desired value but it's not showing up in the textbox. It's very close now. Please help.
Please check the below screenshot
[image]

Comment: I read it.But didn't get what to to. Please help a bit more.

Comment: show `data` from `parseJSON` or try `$('#bills-num').val(data.num)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#bills-num').val(getNum["num"]);
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.